# Access GraphQL Schema without Authentication

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

Currently when setting up Authentication & Authorization with Hotchocolate, the query and accessing the schema requires an authenticated and authorized user.
However when I want to stitch data from multiple services, I need to access the schema of the other services, usually when doing this in my IDE, I'm not authenticated, so I can't access the schema.

My current workaround is to host every service that I want to stitch together locally without authentication, but depending on the amount of services this is quite a chore. So I was wondering if there is any way to configure that the schema access doesn't need authentication (but the queries still do)?